# solidify modifier material offset error

Tags: modeling, materials, modifiers, solidify-modifier

[image]
I used the material offset of Solidify to create this donut with glowing edges.
[image]
base color material
[image]
bloom material

I'm using two materials, one for the base color of the donut and the other to control the color of the bloom.
However, if I create the emission material (the base color of the donut) first and then create the bloom material, the material offset does not get applied.
If I delete and re-add the emission material in this case, I can use the material offset.
But if I create the bloom material first and then the emission material, the material offset is applied.

Why does this happen?

Here is my file.

[image]